# Ethtool Message Level 255

Tags: networking, internet, interface

I am trying to understand what the following ethtool error means:

```
Current message level: 0x000000ff (255)
                           drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err
```

Is it something that I need to fix? My interface is working fine and I'm able to ping out without any issues. This is going to be a host for some VMs, so I need to make sure my interface runs smoothly. I can paste the entire output from the command if needed.

Comment: This is just the information which "message level" is defined. The 8 bits (`0x000000ff`) marked 'on' define the 8 messages displayed after that. See `man ethtool`, the paragraph on `msglvl`.

Comment: @ridgy thanks for the heads up. Last question does the rx_err (Receive error), and tx_err (Transmit error) indicate an ongoing issue that something is wrong? Because it appears as if everything is working as it should. Basically can I ignore this message? Thanks in advance

Comment: Errors are always bad. But if the figures are small compared to the numbers of packages, this is normal, as long as "everything is working as should".

Comment: @ridgy your comments seem answery. Would you care to post them as an answer?